# Angular 7 http post using php fails with 404

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, post, http-post

For my website (programmed with Angular 7) I have built a contact form which I use to send a JSON object to a PHP file.

[Screenshot console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9OQp.png)

The MessageService passes the absolute path to the PHP file and the message object in POST. The POST works, but I get a 404 back.

**message.service.ts**

```
export class MessageService {
  baseUrl = '<domain>/dev/src/app/entities/contact/message.php';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  send(message: Message) {
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl, { data: message }).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('Sent Data', data);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log('Something went wrong', error);
    });
  }
}
```

**message.php**

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

  $post = file_get_contents('php://input');

  echo $postdata;
?>
```

MessageService and message.php are in the same folder. But I'm not sure if the absolute path in the POST is correct.

[Screenshot file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntXiD.png)

I'd be happy if you could help me solve my problem.

Many thanks in advance

Sascha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`
 intead of
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);`

Some browsers doesn't set `HTTP_ORIGIN` and it's not secure to use